# Holomorphic functions with finite fibers

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Suppose $f\colon\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is holomorphic and injective. Then, $f$ is a polynomial (and in fact, linear,) by observing that otherwise $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$ so $f(\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|>1\})$ is dense in $\mathbb C$.

> Is assuming $f$ has finite fibers enough to conclude $f$ is a polynomial?

I believe an example as simple as $f(z)=ze^z$ may work, but I cannot prove it. On the other hand, the same argument does not transfer word-for-word.

Comment: $f(z) = z e^z$ may work for what?  It certainly does not have finite fibers.  In fact the solutions of $z e^z = y$ are the branches of $W(y)$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function, and there are infinitely many of those branches.

Comment: Ahh, interesting, thanks! I'll need to think harder to cook-up a counter-example.

Answer (score 4):

Picard's  great theorem implies that any non polynomial entire function must satisfy the following: there is at most one $y \in \mathbb C$ such that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is finite.

So yes, the only entire maps such that all fibers are finite are polynomial maps.

Comment: Ahh ok, all one needs is to look at $\{f(z):|z|>N\}$ for all integers $N>0$!